# How to set condition in a list to check if the value is less than 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a weight average function,
There are four exceptions and I am stuck in how to set these conditions:

1. a weight is less than 0 or greater than 100
2. the weights do not add to 100
3. the number of weights and grades are not equal
4. a grade is below 0

Here's my code:

```
def weighted_avg(grades,weights):
    if sum(weights)<0:
        print("weight is less than 0")
    elif sum(weights)>100:
        print("weight is greater than 100")
    elif sum(weights)!=100:
        print("weight do not add to 100")
    elif for x in grades:
            if grades[x]<0:
            print("a grade is less than 0")
    else:
        s=0
        for x, y in zip(grades,weights):
            s+=x*y
        return s/sum(weights)

print(weighted_avg(grades4, weights4) == 85.0)
```

I am not sure which part I was missing in my code.

Comment: Replace `if grades[x]<0:` by `if x<0:`

Comment: Thanks, but I got the syntax error elif for x in grades:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `elif for` is wrong! also your code indent in `if grades[x]<0` is wrong

Comment: When you actually raise Exceptions instead of printing an error message, you can get rid of all the "elif" stuff. I also don't see any real use in the first two tests. Finally, the test "!=100" is likely to fail where it shouldn't, if you have floating point input values. And please provide sample input values and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a little bit:

```
def weighted_avg(grades,weights):
    total_weight = sum(weights)
    if total_weight < 0 or total_weight > 100:
        print("Total weights not between 0 and 100")
    elif total_weight != 100:
        print("Total weights do not total 100")
    elif any(x < 0 for x in grades):
        print("A grade is less than 0")
    else:
        cumulative_grades = sum(x * y for x, y in zip(grades,weights))
        return cumulative_grades/total_weight
    return 0

print(weighted_avg(grades4, weights4) == 85.0)
```

You can't use a `for` statement as part of an `if`/`elif` condition, but you can simplify your loop so that it can be checked (without iterating through the whole list) by using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). You  should also calculate the `total_weight` once, to reduce duplicate computations. [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) can also take a comprehension to get your total.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this question when I change the order

```
def weighted_avg(grades,weights):
    for x in grades:
        if x<0:
            print("a grade is less than 0")     
    if sum(weights)<0:
        print("weight is less than 0")
    elif sum(weights)>100:
        print("weight is greater than 100")
    elif sum(weights)!=100:
        print("weight do not add to 100")
    else:
        s=0
        for x, y in zip(grades,weights):
            s+=x*y
        return s/sum(weights)

print(weighted_avg(grades4, weights4) == 85.0)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve your problem. Because now you have multiple prints.